# Displaying rows in which the column value does not appear in the same group of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write the right query, but they show incorrect results.
For example, I have table ABC:

```
id   a_id   b_id    c
1    10     100
2    10     111
3    11     111 
4    11     222     
5    11     333     111&&222&&333
6    12     444 
7    12     555     444&&111
```

In column c there can only be b_id with && that belong to the same a_id.
For example, this record is incorrect:

```
7    12     555     444&111
```

because 111 is in a_id 10 or 11 not 12. How can I find it?
I need to find all rows where occur (invalid) values b_id in column C that are not in the same a_id.
The Sql(postgresql) doesn't work properly, why? Thanks for any help.

My sql:

```
    SELECT * from ABC x
    WHERE x.id IN (SELECT y.id
            FROM ABC y 
    WHERE x.a_id = y.a_ai AND y.c NOT LIKE '%'||x.b_id||'%'
```

Comment: You have tagged three DBMS products. Does it mean, the query should work in all of them or any of them?

Comment: Since you've mentioned "postgresql" - I've removed `mysql` and `sql-server` tags.

Comment: Paul the query should find all incorrect records in which column C has the wrong value b_id. Think of a_id as a group and b_id as users in this group and C can contain any number of users only from its group, it cannot from another one as in the last row with id 7. There may be 444 and / or 555 .  Ok thanks for removing tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_split_to_table()` to split the delimited string into rows. Then use an *anti-join* method, to find not matching entries:

```
with t1 as (
  select *, regexp_split_to_table(c, '&&')::int AS split_c
  from abc
  where c <> ''
)
select distinct t1.id, t1.a_id, t1.b_id, t1.c
from t1
left join abc t2
  on  t2.a_id = t1.a_id
  and t2.b_id = t1.split_c
where t2.a_id is null
```

See [demo on db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nBwfwVeBYstVGUSqq7mGC6/0)

Instead of an *anti-join*, you can also use a `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
with t1 as (
  select *, regexp_split_to_table(c, '&&')::int AS split_c
  from abc
  where c <> ''
)
select distinct t1.id, t1.a_id, t1.b_id, t1.c
from t1
where not exists (
  select *
  from abc t2
  where t2.a_id = t1.a_id
    and t2.b_id = t1.split_c
)
```

If you also want to know, which value in `c` is wrong, replace `select distinct ...` with `select t1.*`. You will find the "wrong" value in `split_c` column. Or use `GROUP BY` and `array_agg()` to list all wrong values in a single row:

```
with t1 as (
  select *, regexp_split_to_table(c, '&&')::int AS split_c
  from abc
  where c <> ''
)
select t1.id, t1.a_id, t1.b_id, t1.c, array_agg(t1.split_c) as wrong_c
from t1
left join abc t2
  on  t2.a_id = t1.a_id
  and t2.b_id = t1.split_c
where t2.a_id is null
group by t1.id, t1.a_id, t1.b_id, t1.c
```

Comment: Thank you Paul again for your valuable advice!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `b_id` is unique in the table, you can use:

```
select abc.*
from abc
where exists (select 1
              from abc abc2
              where abc2.a_id = abc.a_id and
                    concat('&&', abc2.c, '&&') not like concat('%&&', abc.b_id, '&&%')
             );
```

Comment: @ Hi Gordon. I'm sorry I didn't give it but b_id is not unique